# jQuery show function does not work

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am trying to simply start with the nav divs hidden and then show them when the mouse is hovering over them.

I have tried using the .hover function with .show() and .hide and .toggle. I have also tried the mouseeneter and mouseleave function with show and hide and the toggle function.

The really weird thing is I can get it to kind of work in reverse. I can get it to hide on mouse over and show on mouse exit, although it does flicker while the mouse is inside the div.

This is the html and jQuery:

```
<html>

<head><title>Divs</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="divs.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">



        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("div.nav").mouseenter(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).show();
            }).mouseleave(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).hide();
            });

        });

    </script>

</head>


<body>


    <div id="mask">

        <div id="leftNav" class="nav"></div>

        <div id="rightNav" class="nav"></div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

This is the code I have attempted to use for the .hover function:

```
$("div.nav").hover(function() {
                $(this).toggle();
            }, function() {
                $(this).toggle();
            });
```

This is the CSS:

```
div#mask {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#4b4747;
}

div.nav {
    display:none;
}

div#leftNav {
    background-color:red;
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8000;
}

div#rightNav {
    background-color:red;
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

div#pictures {
    display:none;
}
```

I have tried multiple variations of each method. What am I missing here?

Comment: can you jsfiddle.net it?

Comment: [here's the working fiddle using opacity.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/GXtzF/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `.hover()` or other mouse-related events on an element with `display: none` which is what an element is set to with `.hide()` and what your CSS initially sets it to.  Such elements do not receive mouse events so you will never get the intial `.hover()` or other mouse event event.

You can change your logic to fade the opacity to zero rather than hide them.  This will make them not visible, but they will still receive mouse events.

Change to:

```
div.nav {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("div.nav").hover(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1});
        }, function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).animate({opacity: 0});
        });

    });
```

The main difference between using opacity and between using hide/show is that the element will still occupy space in your page when setting the opacity (which is why it can still receive events), but when you hide() it, it will no longer occupy any space in the page (which is why it doesn't receive any mouse events).

Comment: Thank you. Now that you say it, it seems obvious.

Answer (score 1):

please  set the MouseEnter Event For Other Element
becase leftnav and rightnav first time is display none
and you can not riase MouseEnter For this